# Installing OPAM System-Wide?

Tags: configuration, installation, ocaml, homebrew, opam

I've made a few attempts to install OPAM system-wide via Homebrew and `opam init`, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.  How should I go about trying this again?

Answer (score 5):

First of all it is not recommended to install it system wide. But if you still want, then this are the steps:

1. `sudo brew install opam`    # installs `opam` executable system-wide
2. `sudo mkdir -p /opt/opam`   # create a home for opam
3. `sudo opam init --root=/opt/opam --comp=4.02.1`
4. `eval $(opam config env)`   # activate the environment
5. `ocaml` # run ocaml to make sure, that everything went fine

Some footnotes: I'm expecting that you've failed on your previous attempts, because you didn't specify the compiler version and didn't install system compiler. I still suggest you to reconsider, and install `opam` locally. To do that you need to perform the following:

1. `brew install opam`    # installs `opam` executable system-wide
2. `opam init --comp=4.02.1`
3. `eval $(opam config env)`   # activate the environment
4. `ocaml` # run ocaml to make sure, that everything went fine

Comment: OK, that's cool.  Maybe why it wasn't working for me is because I was trying to install OPAM in `/usr/local/opam`?  Just why exactly, though, is it not recommended for users to install OPAM system-wide?  I know that some other users have come across some bugs (see [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/398) and [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/746)) in their attempts to do so, but these bugs look like they're just related to setup issues like the ones I was having the other day…

Comment: there are locks in opam on some operations that would lock everyone instead of individuals.

Comment: @nlucaroni:  What do 'locks' have to do with anything?

Comment: opam was designed mostly in that way. So it is usually better to use any tool in a way it was designed.